# VS 2010 - Project takes 30+ minutes to save

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

My OS is Win7 64 bit, 6 gig ram, running on a VM.

IDE - VS2010

Project is on the local disk of my VM

I've been working (doing maintenance) on this project on & off for several years now (it's part of the core business where I work).  When I open the project, I can open the code window (for a form), make changes & save them, no problems.

Just recently when I display the UI (still in VS), it will take a while to render (3-5 seconds). If I make a change to a form, or any object on a form, when I save it or attempt to go back to the code, VS hangs & eats up 80-95% of the CPU for 25-30 minutes, then the save completes.

I have repaired VS with no luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Any Visual Studio extensions? Could you disable them and retry?

Comment: there are only 2 extensions installed, Process Template Editor & WITDesigner, both for TFS & cannot be disabled. I unbinded to project from source  control & had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to post an answer below because it can be anthing. You are the only person who has access to the computer and it is only who can definitely find this out. However, I can give you ideas what you can try and then we can expand the answer.

1. Take [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) from Microsoft and examine what Visual Studio is actually doing during that long period. Please see MSDN Blog [Tips on troubleshooting Visual Studio Performance issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2015/05/19/tips-on-troubleshooting-visual-studio-performance-issues.aspx) on how to understand the output.
2. Create simple project and check whether the behavior is there as well.
3. Create new project and move all your stuff from old project into new project and check whether Visual Studio will be fast or slow.
4. After backup, work with old project, remove all its parts and see whether VS performance goes to normal. If it will do, return to full old project and delete its parts one-by-one (or by different method). After speeding up the VS, you will get understanding which part was the culprit. (The one you recently removed.)

I would do the some steps if I had the problem with my VS. These issues tend to sound like "prepare some unplanned time for me, better couple of hours.". I'm sorry to see you are experiencing this.

Again, this is not a definite answer, only steps most likely guiding you to the solution.

Comment: @larryr -  pardon, I'm not quite sure if I understand: except of converting the project, did you also upgrade your VS2010 to 2012?